# Adding .h & .m files in iPhone library

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

I am creating a library to share with other projects. I am adding the required .h files in "Copy Headers" & .m files in "Compiled Sources" folder.

I noticed one thing that even if I do not add some .h files & add just a .m file my library works fine but reverse is not true. Why it is so that .h file is not mandatory to add in the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.h (header files) contain class, type, function, and constant declarations.
So no actual code. Header files are there to let (for instance) xcode know what methods and  properties are declared in that specific class.

Comment: I understand that. So, would it be OK if I do not add any .h file in my library & just the .m files?

Comment: If you leave out the .h file, you'll get warnings that specific methods can't be found or variables are undeclared. So you need that .h file next to the library (.a)